# Calling main method from JNI fails

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I created a C++ class that is supposed to call `Main.main` by following: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502.

I didn't get it to work so I followed: http://www.coderanch.com/t/525082/CPP/create-JVM-native-code-call

and :

imp_JNI_Crea">http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263687/Linker-error-undefined-reference-to-*imp*_JNI_Crea

None of which worked. So I changed my code back to what the Invocation API article by oracle says (the first link).

My C++ code looks like:

In JNI.hpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

class Jvm
{
private:
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs jvm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options;

public:
    Jvm();
};
```

In JNI.cpp file:

```
Jvm::Jvm()
{
    options = new JavaVMOption[3];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Loader/build/classes";
    options[2].optionString = "-verbose:class";

    jvm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    jvm_args.nOptions = 3;
    jvm_args.options = options;
    jvm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    //JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&jvm_args);
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), &jvm_args);

    jclass MainClass = env->FindClass("loader.Main");


    //Crashes on the next line:
    jmethodID MainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(MainClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    MessageBox(NULL, "", "", 0);

    Sleep(1000);

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    delete[] options;
}
```

My java code looks like:

```
package loader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JavaProcess.exec(ClientApplet.class);
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

And the verbose prints:

```
[Loaded loader.Main from file:/C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Loader/build/classes/]

Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 1.730 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it fail to call the method? 
The `JNI.dll` that I loaded is from: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` because the latest `Java 7u25` doesn't have a `bin\client\jvm.dll`.

I even statically linked to the jvm.lib: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib\jvm.lib`.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the C++ code where you actually *call* the `main` method of the Java class? You just extract it.

Comment: Regarding the crash, you never do any kind of failure checking.

Comment: I know but it crashes on just doing that alone. I did call it but it doesn't even get to the called line. It crashes my program with that weird result just extracting it.  MainClass is 0 after the FindClass("loader.Main")

I removed all the error checking to make it easier to read.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I solved it! You see the line that says `env->FindClass("loader.Main");`.. I changed it to:  `env->FindClass("loader/Main");`  The Dot changed to a Slash and it finds it just fine now. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it. I won't let me solve my own question.

Comment: @Brandon Even though this was answered, you never posted the call method: `env->CallStaticVoidMethod(MainClass , MainMethod, NULL);`  Did you experience a need to pass in an argument (such as NULL) in order for it to work?  Or could you omit it?

Comment: @NickMiller; You can omit it (NULL) only if the class that has the method does not need it (basically only if `main` does not use the argument.. In that case, the JVM will pass "null" as the argument. You can do `env->CallStaticVoidMethod(MainClass, MainMethod)` without passing null. You can pass null if you want. It's optional and makes no difference. If the class uses the argument, you need to do `arr = env->newObjectArray(size, stringClass, NULL);` and pass that as the argument (aka a string array).

Comment: @Brandon That is the behavior I expected.  Omitting NULL in my case prevents my Java code from running, so I am passing it in anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jclass MainClass = env->FindClass("loader.Main");
```

This is wrong. You have to use slashes instead of dots when using JNI functions, just like in method signatures.

The correct code is:

```
jclass MainClass = env->FindClass("loader/Main");
```